# TypeScript - Perform multiple actions in a ternary condition

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to execute multiple actions within a ternary condition? Something similar to the following (which does not work):

```
condition ? () => {
    // Perform multiple actions within this delegate function if the condition is true
} : // Perform an action if the condition is false;
```

Comment: Avoid using ternary operators for too complex things. Just use an if-else statement instead. Ternary operators are best used for simple and small conditional assignments.

Comment: not enough that it's an easy to find question, it's even easier to just test it before asking...

Comment: Nice find, thanks @lexith! I did do a quick search before hand, but found nothing regarding TypeScript. I have it working now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do this with a single function, it's simple:

```
condition ? console.log("true") : console.log("false");
```

If you want multiple functions to be called, it's a bit more complex:

```
condition 
    ? (() => {
        console.log("true");
        console.log("still true");
    })()
    : (() => {
        console.log("false");
        console.log("still false")
    })();
```

This is because when you have a ternary, it will immediately invoke whatever is inside the block. So if you want to call a function, you need to execute that function with `()`.

---

Personally, though, I would recommend against this. I think it is much less clear than:

```
if (condition) {
    console.log("true");
    console.log("still true");
} else {
    console.log("true");
    console.log("still true");
}
```

Comment: Just tried wrapping it like this and it worked, thanks! You beat me to it haha.

Comment: In a situation where there are a lot of actions between conditions, yes, I would agree with using if/else. But in my case, I'm only executing 2 actions if true, and a single action if false, so it's easy to keep it clean.